# Showing that the set of polynomials is convex

Tags: polynomials, convex-analysis

How to show that the set of polynomials of $x^2+bx+c$ having at least one real root, is convex?

Let $x^2+b_1x+c_1$ and $x^2+b_2x+c_2$ have at least one real root. Need to show that $\alpha(x^2+b_1x+c_1) + (1-\alpha)(x^2+b_2x+c_2)$ when $0<\alpha<1$ has a real root too.

Comment: Fun question, +1. You might want to make your title a little more explicit. Stated like that, it seems trivial.

Comment: Not true.  Consider $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$.

Comment: @hardmath Perfect counterexample. This should be an answer.

Comment: @julien:  Let's wait a bit to see if Ashot has forgotten to mention part of the question.

Comment: Perhaps one could look at the discriminant of $\alpha(x^2+b_1x+c_1) + (1-\alpha)(x^2+b_2x+c_2)$ and use that to derive the missing condition.

Comment: I suspect the "at least one root" was meant to be common to all polynomials in the set (of monic polynomials).  The set would then be convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated the claim is false.  The monic quadratic polynomials $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$, for example, each have at least one real root, but their midpoint $x^2 + x + \frac{1}{2}$ has no real root.

But if the problem concerned the set of monic quadratic polynomials which have a specific real root $r$ *in common*, then that set would be convex.  In other words, if both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are monic quadratic polynomials such that $p(r)=q(r)=0$, and $0 \le \alpha \le 1$, then $\alpha p(x) + (1 - \alpha) q(x)$ is also monic quadratic with root $r$.

Comment: And lest anyone think that this counterexample exists only because both $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ have exactly one real root, just subtract $0.0001$ from all the polynomials.